# How to select different percentages of data based in a column value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to query a table that has a "gender" column, like so:

```
| id | gender | name    |
-------------------------
| 1  | M      | Michael |
-------------------------
| 2  | F      | Hanna   |
-------------------------
| 3  | M      | Louie   |
-------------------------
```

And I need to extract the first N results which have, for example 80% males and 20% females. So, if I needed 1000 results I would want to retrieve 800 males and 200 females.

1. Is it possible to do it in a single query? How?
2. If I don't have enough records (imagine I have only 700 males on the example above) is it possible to select 700 / 300 automatically?

Comment: For scenario 2, what is supposed to happen?

Comment: I've edited my answer to better explain myself.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know enough SQL to give the answer in terms of code, but I can give the logic:

I'd suggest an SP and have a value, N (number you are selecting) and take n*.8 and select that where gender is M, count your rows returned as numResultsMale, and select N-(numResultsMale) where gender is F

Comment: On a side note, `gender` as boolean or `M`/`F` will get you or your users into some hassle sooner or later. It's usually a good idea to allow 'other' or 'unspecified'. There are folks out there who aren't 100% male or 100% female (biologically and/or psycologically, by birth or by alteration).

Comment: @CraigRinger, maybe they want it that way. It is not always a goal to fulfill all the requirements of all the users. I understand your comment and agree that it is valid in many cases, but I believe we should let him store the gender as boolean if he wants to.

Comment: Actually the example is a dummy table, I don't even have a gender column in the table that I want to do this but I thought this was an example that would be easy to understand the problem. I agree with you and I have that on my users table actually :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to get as many 'M' as you can, but not more than your percentage and then get enough 'F' so you have total 1000 rows:

```
with cte_m as (
    select * from Table1 where gender = 'M' limit (1000 * 0.8)
), cte as (
    select *, 0 as ord from cte_m
    union all
    select *, 1 as ord from Table1 where gender = 'F'
    order by ord
    limit 1000
)
select id, gender, name
from cte
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/90eff/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, which assumes you are supplying a row count ("lmt"), and floats for the M/F distribution:

```
create table gen (
id     integer,
gender text,
name   text
);

-- inserts 75% males and 25% females into the source table ("gen")
insert into gen select n, case when mod(n,5) = 0 then 'F' else 'M' end, (case when mod(n,5) = 0 then 'F' else 'M' end)||'_'||n::text
from generate_series(1,20000) n


-- extract 80/20 M vs F
with conf as (select 1000 as lmt, .80::FLOAT as mpct, .20::FLOAT as fpct),
     g as (select id,gender,name,row_number() over (partition by gender order by gender) rn from gen)
select *
from g
where (gender = 'M' and rn <= (select lmt*mpct from conf))
or (gender = 'F' and rn <= (select lmt*fpct from conf));


-- Same query, to show the percent M vs F:
with conf as (select 1000 as lmt, .80::FLOAT as mpct, .20::FLOAT as fpct),
     g as (select id,gender,name,row_number() over (partition by gender order by gender) rn from gen)
select gender,count(*)
from (
    select *
    from g
    where (gender = 'M' and rn <= (select lmt*mpct from conf))
    or (gender = 'F' and rn <= (select lmt*fpct from conf))
    ) y
group by gender
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have postgresql with me, but the first scenario is pretty easy with a union in MS SQL 2012. I assume you can do it similarly in postgre:

```
declare @MaxRows            INT
        ,@PercentageMale    INT
        ,@PercentageFemale  INT

select      @MaxRows = 1000
            ,@PercentageMale = 80
            ,@PercentageFemale = 20

select  top (@MaxRows*@PercentageMale/100)  *
FROM        someTable
WHERE       Gender = 'M'
UNION
select  top (@MaxRows*@PercentageFemale/100)    *
FROM        someTable
WHERE       Gender = 'F'
```

The second bit is actually quite easy. Basically you want to select the top % of males, and then fill the rest of the list with females, up to the total number of rows. The number of females is not actually relavent:

```
declare @MaxRows            INT
        ,@PercentageMale    INT

select      @MaxRows = 1000
            ,@PercentageMale = 80

SELECT TOP @MaxRows *
FROM
(
    select  top (@MaxRows*@PercentageMale/100)  *
    FROM        someTable
    WHERE       Gender = 'M'
    UNION
    select  top (@MaxRows)  * --we never want more than @MaxRows 
                              --so no need to check for a %, 
                              --just fill in the rest of the data set
    FROM        someTable
    WHERE       Gender = 'F'
) a
```